# Using CacheListener with GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, caching

I store instances of Domain objects in GAE's memcache using the *javax.cache* API. I'd like to be notified as soon any instance is evicted due to storage limitations or anything else. Is a *CacheListener* the solution for that? Is GAE calling *CacheListener.evict(Object o)* when it's removing instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appengine [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/usingjcache.html#Features_Not_Supported)  state that onEvict() is not supported.

> The JCache listener API is partially supported for listeners that can execute during the processing of a app's API call, such as for onPut and onRemove listeners. Listeners that require background processing, like onEvict, are not supported.

Comment: Does "onPut" or "onRemove" only work locally, or also across machines (put on one machine, have the listener called on all machines)?

Comment: Only locally. *extra text to make SO happy*